# Editing an xsd with imported schemas from dependencies in Eclipse

Tags: jaxb, eclipse-wtp, xmlcatalog, m2e-wtp

I have a maven project A with an /xsd/a.xsd in it's classpath.
I also have the project B with an /xsd/b.xsd that refers to /xsd/a.xsd through a catalog entry.
The catalog entry looks like this:

```
PUBLIC "http://foo.org/a" "maven:org.foo:a:jar::!/xsd/a.xsd"
```

Note the maven protocol in the url. The catalog is used by the org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb22-plugin to generate the JAXB annotated Java classes with episodes from dependencies.

Everything is good so far.

Now I would like to edit /xsd/b.xsd in Eclipse. Eclipse report a warning on:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://foo.org/a" />
```

as it cannot find the /xsd/a.xsd without a schemaLocation attribute. Eclipse does not recognize the catalog entry defined above.

The workaround found is to add a catalog entry in Eclipse / Window / Preferences / XML / XML Catalog:

```
PUBLIC "http://foo.org/a" "jar:file:/home/alain/maven/repository/org/foo/a/1.0-SNAPSHOT/a-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/xsd/a.xsd"
```

Note the reference to my local repository (maven is a link to .m2) and to a specific version of the dependent project a.

Anyone having faced this issue and found a better workaround?

Comment: Facing the same issue, but haven't found any better workaround. Also it's a PITA that you cannot even point directly to `.m2` directory because of the dot.

Answer (score 1):

The Best I can come up with is :

- extract the xsds  of the jar in the project with maven-dependency-plugin:unpack
- reference the xsds from here in Eclipse / Window / Preferences / XML / XML Catalog.

At least there will be no reference to local path/version.

Note that if you have already a catalog for jaxb, it is possible to import it directly in eclipse, without having to edit one by one (Via import menu, not in XML Catalog).

Comment: extracting the .xsds defeats the point of having a catalog, then you wouldn't need the catalog at all. Also, even if you have a catalog for jaxb, you cannot import it to Eclipse if it contains a maven reference as Eclipse doesn't understand it.